# kernel freezing on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, crash

I recently switched to ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop which is a thinkpad P51. I am having the issue that sometimes the login desktop freezes in the sense that I am able to move the cursor and interact with the desktop but nothing will run. For instance I can shutdown but it will not shutdown and seems to just freeze at that state, at many points in time, I need to force shutdown. I am not sure what the problem is or even how to go abouts debugging it.

I have posted a picture of what it looks like on the login page:

[image]

I am using kernel version 4.10. The specs for my computer are as follows:

```
-Computer-
Processor : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory : 65684MB (2271MB used)
Operating System : Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
User Name : johnz (johnz)
Date/Time : Sun 07 Jan 2018 01:21:34 AM EST
-Display-
Resolution : 3840x2160 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : Unknown
X11 Vendor : The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
Audio Adapter : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
-Input Devices-
Sleep Button
Lid Switch
Power Button
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Video Bus
Video Bus
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0
Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0
Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0
TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
Integrated Camera
ThinkPad Extra Buttons
HDA Intel PCH Mic
HDA Intel PCH Headphone
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm : 3=
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm : 7=
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm : 8=
-Printers-
No printers found
-SCSI Disks-
ATA Samsung SSD 850
```

When I check xsession-errors, it has the following message:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

This is quite annoying because everytime i need to force shutdown, and I would really like to fix this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: can you switch to one of the consoles and check .xsession-errors in your $HOME?

Comment: it has the following: `openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0`

Comment: @PutsandCalls same issue here.